# Mirroring a network drive using one drive

Tags: onedrive, mirroring

I have a Networked Z:\Reports folder that files are saved to automatically. I want these reports to be available for sharing via one drive. So far the only method I can see for adding stuff to one drive is drag and drop which is not useful for my purpose, as the files come in at random times and need to be mirrored as soon as they are available.

How can I set things up such that my one drive is automatically scanning z:\reports and mirroring it exactly even as new files come in? Is this even possible? If it is not possible in one drive but is possible in some other cloud  storage product (google drive etc) that is an acceptable answer also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I couldn't figure this out but have found a workaround. I used the open source program [Dropit](http://www.dropitproject.com/) and set up a rule to automatically move any files that land in my Z:\reports folder to my one drive folder. It's a bit of a inelegant solution but definitely does the job.